# The type or namespace name `Kinect' does not exist in the namespace `Microsoft'

Tags: c#, namespaces, unity-game-engine, kinect

I am using Unity to develop a game and I want to use Kinect so I add a reference to `Microsoft.Kinect.ddl` and I have the following code (nothing impressive):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.Kinect;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        print(KinectSensor.KinectSensors.Count);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Visual Studio does not mark any error but when I am trying to run it using Unity I am getting a compilation error `The type or namespace name Kinect does not exist in the namespace Microsoft` . Any idea how can I fix that?

Comment: Which .NET version is your project?

Comment: I _think_ Microsoft.Kinect requires 4.0.

Comment: http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/vs2010-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-problem/

Answer (score 0):

See [this page](http://wiki.etc.cmu.edu/unity3d/index.php/Microsoft_Kinect_-_Microsoft_SDK#Integrating_with_Unity) for using the SDK with unity. It does have some obvious errors though (as pointed out in the documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

I am using k2examples asset from the asset store, and I ran into the same problem... since you are not using the same asset, this might not solve the problem, but you can give it a try:

import the standard assets.